# How to draw a density plot?

Tags: r, plotting

This is my R script to draw the density plot:

```
df <- iris
plot(density(df$Sepal.Length), main="Density Plot", ylab="Frequency", sub=paste("Skewness:", round(e1071::skewness(df$Sepal.Length), 2)))
```

Is there a way to plot three density plots (one for every species: setosa, virginica and versicolor) in the same graph?

Comment: try seaborns density plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plotting I prefer to use the `ggplot2` package since I find it easier to use and more versatile. Using this package you can easily plot multiple density plots:

```
library(ggplot2)

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, colour=Species)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]